# Probability - independence questions

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

1) Given that two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if $\text{Pr}(A∩B)=\text{Pr}(A)\text{Pr}(B)$, prove that if $\text{Pr}(B)>0$ then $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $\text{Pr}(A|B)=\text{Pr}(A)$.

My thinking is that if $\text{Pr}(A|B) = \text{Pr}(A∩B)/\text{Pr}(B) = \text{Pr}(A)$, then $\text{Pr}(B)$ must be $1$ and $\text{Pr}(A∩B)$ has to be $\text{Pr}(A)$. But I'm not sure what to do after that.

2) Let $A$ and $B$ be independent events. Show $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ are also independent, where $\overline{A}=Ω \setminus A$.

Comment: "Then $Pr(B)$ must be $1$ and $Pr(A\cap B)$ has to be $Pr(A)$"... no, that's not quite it.  $Pr(B)$ could be anything, it doesn't have to be equal to one just as $Pr(A\cap B)$ doesn't have to be equal to $Pr(A)$.  Read the very first sentence you wrote and use that knowledge.  It says that $\color{blue}{Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)Pr(B)}$ so... $Pr(A\mid B) = \frac{\color{blue}{Pr(A\cap B)}}{Pr(B)}=\dots$

Comment: For the second part, note that $Pr(\overline{A}\cap \overline{B})=Pr(\overline{(A\cup B)}) = 1-Pr(A\cup B)=\dots$ and again use what you know from the first sentence and inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $\textbf{Proof}$. Assume $\text{Pr}(B)>0$. Assume that the events $A$ and $B$ are independent. Then 
$$
\text{Pr}(A|B) = \dfrac{\text{Pr}(A\cap B)}{\text{Pr}(B)} = \dfrac{\text{Pr}(A)\text{Pr}(B)}{\text{Pr}(B)} = \text{Pr}(A).
$$

On the other hand, if $\text{Pr}(A|B)=\text{Pr}(A)$, then 
$$
\text{Pr}(A|B) = \dfrac{\text{Pr}(A \cap B)}{\text{Pr}(B)}=\text{Pr}(A).
$$

Since $\text{Pr}(A\cap B)=\text{Pr}(A)\text{Pr}(B)$, we conclude that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

2) $\textbf{Proof}$. Assume $A$ and $B$ are independent events. Let $\overline{A}=\Omega\setminus A$. 
Then we have 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Pr}(\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}) &= \text{Pr}((\Omega\setminus A) \cap (\Omega\setminus B)) \\ 
&= \text{Pr}(\Omega\setminus (A\cup B)) \\ 
&= \text{Pr}(\Omega) - \text{Pr}(A\cup B) \\ 
&= 1 - (\text{Pr}(A)+\text{Pr}(B)-\text{Pr}(A\cap B)) \\ 
&= 1 - (\text{Pr}(A)+\text{Pr}(B)-\text{Pr}(A) \text{Pr}(B)) \\ 
&= 1 - (\text{Pr}(A)+\text{Pr}(B))+\text{Pr}(A) \text{Pr}(B). \\ 
\end{aligned}
$$

On the other hand, 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Pr}(\overline{A})\text{Pr}(\overline{B}) &= 
(1-\text{Pr}(A))(1-\text{Pr}(B)) \\ 
&= 1-(\text{Pr}(A)+\text{Pr}(B)) +\text{Pr}(A)\text{Pr}(B). \\  
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $\text{Pr}(\overline{A}\cap \overline{B})=\text{Pr}(\overline{A})\text{Pr}(\overline{B})$, events $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ are also independent.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Use $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) -P(A \cap B)$